# How to find the complex function $u + iv$ if $u - v$ is given?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the complex function $u + iv$ if $u - v$ is given, where $u$ and $v$ are the component functions of the complex function $$f(z)=u(x,y) + iv(x,y).$$ Here, $z = x + iy$.

Comment: Do you know $u$ and $v$ individually? There's not a way to recover $u$ and $v$ from $u - v$.

Comment: If $c \in \mathbb{C}$ is given, the equation $a-b=c$ does not have a unique solution $(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$. In fact, any element of $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ of the form $(\alpha+c,\alpha)$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is arbitrary, solves the problem.

Comment: "Here, **z**..." is a little odd when **z** does not appear elsewhere in your question.

Comment: @sundu : for posterity, please include the requirement that $f$ is analytic.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that $f$ is analytic.

Then we need
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial{x}} (u-v) = \frac{\partial }{\partial y} (u+v)
$$
Since you know the left hand side, you can integrate the right hand side and you will have an arbitrarily *constant of integration* that will be function of $x$.

So now have both $u-v$ and $u+v$ and you can get $u$ and $v$

**Note:** Based on the question posed in the comment

If you call the constant of integration $h(x)$ then from the condition
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} $$
You can get $h'(x)$ from which you have $h(x)$ with a constant of integration. Half of this constant adds to both $u$ and $v$ without affecting $u-v$.

*Worked out example:* 
Suppose that
$$
u - v = {y}^{3}-3\,x\,{y}^{2}-3\,{x}^{2}\,y+{x}^{3}$$
Going through the motions you get
$$
\begin{align}
u &=x^3/3 -3 x y^2 + h(x)/2 \\
v&= -y^3 +3 x^2 y -x^3/3 + h(x)/2
\end{align}
$$
And
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\Rightarrow h'(x) = 3 x^2 \Rightarrow h(x) = x^3 + C
$$
It is easy to verify that
$$
f(z=x+i\,y) = z^3 + C+ i\,C
$$

Not much can you do about the $C + i\, C$

Comment: how do you get around the arbitrary "constant of integration" for $u+v$ (which may depend on $x$ but not $y$)?  See Mercy's comment which gives an example without a unique answer.

Comment: You can't get rid of it. Having constants of integration is not unusual in problems involving integration

Comment: I added a worked out example to illustrate my answer

Answer (score 0):

$(u-v) = \Re((1+i)(u+iv))$ has harmonic conjugate $\Im((1+i)(u+iv))=u+v$ because $f=u+iv$ is analytic. Let $w$ be a harmonic conjugate of $(u-v)$ on the connected domain. Then $w=u+v+C$ for some real constant $C$, and
$$
\begin{align}
        f & = \frac{1}{2}(1-i)(1+i)(u+iv) \\
          & = \frac{1}{2}(1-i)((u-v)+iw-iC) \\
          & = \frac{1}{2}(1-i)((u-v)+iw)-\frac{1}{2}(1+i)C.
\end{align}
$$
So $f$ can be known up to a real constant times $(1+i)$.